# Can I undo NSubstitute's Returns() substitution without recreating the mock?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

Using NSubstitute, I can do this:

```
mock.doStuff().Returns(foo);
```

But for a large test fixture, this isn't appropriate in every test.

So can I "undo" that `Returns()` substitution, or must I recreate the mock before each test? (which is slooooow...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to override the stubbed value -- the last one set will be used.

```
mock.doStuff().Returns(foo);
...
mock.doStuff().Returns(anotherFoo);
```

You can also get fine-grained control over resetting parts of a substitute using [`ClearExtensions`](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/blob/master/Source/NSubstitute.Acceptance.Specs/ClearSubstitute.cs):

```
using NSubstitute.ClearExtensions;
...
mock.ClearSubstitute(ClearOptions.ReturnValues);
```

`ClearExtensions` is available in the 2.0.0 release candidate (and above), so you may need to enable [prerelease packages in NuGet to get that feature](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NSubstitute/2.0.0-rc).

Comment: Does it nuke all return values for a mock, or just the one it's applied to? So is there an intended difference between `mock.ClearSubstitute(ClearOptions.ReturnValues)` and `mock.doStuff().ClearSubstitute(ClearOptions.ReturnValues)`?

Comment: `ClearSubstitute` nukes all returns on a single sub. If you want to reset a single call I think the override approach will work best.

Comment: That's a pity... but it's a nice new feature nonetheless.

Comment: Is there a reason you'd like to reset a single stubbed call to its default, rather than just re-stubbing with a new value?

Comment: My test fixture's tests share a particular mock, which is sloooooow to setup. So I reuse it. But in one test I need to intercept a particular return value, and in another test I need to rely on the default. So would be nice to reset that particular one, instead of recreating the mock from scratch. Maybe in some future version of the library, assuming there are others who have this issue... maybe it's just me!

Comment: Maybe try `mock.doStuff().Returns(default(T))` where `T` is whatever type `doStuff` returns. That's essentially what NSub does for most types.

Comment: You might need ClearSubstitute if you set up a .Throws<Exception> and then need it to not throw anything on a subsequent call.

Comment: @Koja For 4.x and above you can use `.Configure()` so you can call `.Returns` without throwing due to an earlier stub.